# Is there a program which allows me to convert 3-D parametric functions into Cartesian form?

Tags: parametric, computational-mathematics, programming

I have two functions in the form x(a,b) and y(a,b). I need convert them in to the form of y(x) with the aid of a program because the functions are too complicated to be solved by hand.

Comment: give a better example

Comment: What do you mean by that? I thought it was clear.

Comment: What do $a,b$ represent?

Comment: they're just arbitrary variables. My point is, how can I relate x and y when they both depend on a pair of variables which are the same for both x and y?

Comment: If both x and y map a 2d space (parametrized by a,b) into a 1d space (the x or y itself) typically multiple a,b will return the same x value but perhaps not the same y value, so the $y(x)$ mapping is multi valued.

Comment: Thanks, this was perfect.